# Animate specific view with desired animation and directions

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I am trying to animate a view to show and appear with setting the constraint either 0 or 100. The problem I encountered is how to I change the animation style or direction? Because the view will animate from bottom to top but I want to show the view from top to bottom.

I cant use `self.view.layoutIfneeded` because I dont want it to animate the whole view. I just want to animate the specific view with the correct direction. Thanks.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.topButtonView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you show animation video or gif whatever you have ?

Comment: Show the constant that you are changing before calling the `UIView.animate()` method

Comment: @RakeshaShastri
self.headerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 150

Comment: what is the constant before setting it to 150?

Comment: the constant 150 is the original number

Answer (score 1):

Use `CGAffineTransform`

```
// move the view to top 100 offset from current y
self.topButtonView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -100)
// then reset the transform
// it will animate downward (back to it's original position)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
    self.topButtonView.transform = .identity
}, completion: nil)
```